# Saving JWT token in static filed is best practice?

Tags: authentication, jwt

Saving `KeyForHmacSha256`, `TokenIssuer`, `TokenAudience` and `TokenLifetimeMinutes` in static filed is best practice or read these value from config file.

```
public class SecurityConstants
{
    public static readonly byte[] KeyForHmacSha256 = new byte[64];

    public static readonly string TokenIssuer = string.Empty;

    public static readonly string TokenAudience = string.Empty;

    public static readonly double TokenLifetimeMinutes = 1;

    static SecurityConstants()
    {
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        cryptoProvider.GetNonZeroBytes(KeyForHmacSha256);   

        TokenIssuer = "issuer"; 

        TokenAudience = "http://localhost:90";  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As with about anything, the answer is "it depends."

I would certainly make the argument that the `KeyForHmacSha256` variable is pulled from a config file or environment variable, just to keep it out of source control.

Personally, I usually pull in issuer and audience dynamically.  The issuer is pulled from the environment so that I don't have to manually set it in each deploy and the audience is determined by who is requesting the token.

The token lifetime has the best case for just being a static definition.  If you have a need to make it dynamic, you will need to handle that, but setting it explicitly isn't a security issue.